# Make an hour into timestamp

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

How can I make a time,  for example 09, to a UNIX timestamp? I tried `strtotime()` but unsuccessfully. `strtotime("9")` returns nothing.

**Edit**:
It's my fault that I didn't mention before but I'm trying to check if current time + 30 minutes is bigger or equal to time, saved in a mysql DB. I save time in DB as 09, for example (probably there's my mistake).

Comment: An hour of which day? And in what timezone? Timestamps specify *a unique point in time*, which "9 o' clock" certainly is not.

Comment: Just an hour ,no matter the day.In EET(GMT +2 and GMT+3 in the summer)

Comment: @lam3r4370: It doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Jon ,can you tell me which function to use,because i can't use strtotime.If I use strtotime("9 hours") it changes according to the time but my time is the same(09) ,it isn't changing.

Comment: @lam3r4370: **There is no function to make a timestamp for "just an hour"**. You need to specify the year, month, day, minute, second, and timezone as well. If you do, then assuming you picked your local (server's!) timezone, `mktime` would be the one to use. Or, most likely, a timestamp is not what you need. Telling us which problem you want to solve might help.

Comment: A UNIX timestamp is a **point** in time, while "1 hour" is a **duration** of time. You can't convert directly between them, just like you can't convert an inch to gallons. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php vs. http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mktime

```
int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, int $month = date("n") [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: `if (strtotime("+30 minutes") >= mktime(9,00) AND mktime(9,00) >= strtotime("now")) {
 echo "OK";
}`
Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

While both answers so far are probably better, I thought I'd offer a "cute" solution that still uses `strtotime()`:

```
$hour = "09";
echo strtotime("Today $hour:00");
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/k9U4BiKN

Comment: Agreed, it's not the most efficient solution since PHP has to go through the overhead of parsing that string but I like the readability of it :)

Answer (score 0):

The additional information you provided in the edit clarifies one or two things. Generating a timestamp for comparison probably won't do much good if the database value is a string representing the hour. In this case, you can just as well compare the hour values as numbers:

```
// Value from database
$db_hour = '09';

// Hour 30 minutes from now
$compare_hour = date('H', strtotime('+30 minutes'));

// Check if current time + 30 minutes is bigger
if (intval($compare_hour) >= intval($db_hour))
```

If the database hour values are between 0 and 23, the comparison will of course always return true between 22:30 and 23:29.

Note: Had the MySQL table field been a timestamp field, you could get just the hour part with "SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM your_field) AS db_hour FROM your_table;"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

Comment: If the $db_hour='09:30' ,the `echo intval("9:30")` function returns 9

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize you needed minutes (and maybe seconds?) as well. Dealing with timestamps as in your comment to Luka's answer is certainly the way to go when things get more complicated.